# How i create two types in an interface<T, I> inherited two types interface<T, I>

Tags: c#, generics, types

```
// T => a class
// I => Guid, int etc..

public interface IBaseX<T, I> 
       where T : BaseY<I> {..}
public class BaseX<T, I> : IBaseX<T, I> 
       where T : BaseY<I> {..}

// it works but,

public interface IMyClass<T, I> 
       where T : IBaseX<T, I> {..}
public class MyClass<T, I> 
       where T : BaseX<T, I>, IMyClass<T, I>

// this not works, why not?
```

Error:
the type T cannot be used as type parameter T in the generic type or method IBaseX. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from T to BaseY

---

there are some issues, i m writing renew:

i have an orm project, includes:

at the project root:
BaseEntity.cs:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T>
{
    public T ID { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

content folder:
Page.cs:

```
public class Page : BaseEntity<int>
{
    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ....
 }
```

PageComment.cs:

```
public class PageComment : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public int PageID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(175)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

i have a datalayer project, includes:

base folder:

IBaseDAL.cs:

```
public interface IBaseDAL<T, I> where T : BaseEntity<I>
{
    void Save(T e, string who, WebsiteContext ctx = null);
    void Update(T e, string who, WebsiteContext ctx = null);
    void Delete(T e, string who, WebsiteContext ctx = null);

}
```

BaseDAL.cs:

```
public class BaseDAL<T, I> : IBaseDAL<T, I> where T : BaseEntity<I>
{
    public void Save(T e, string who, WebsiteContext ctx = null) { ... }
}
```

comment folder:

ICommentDAL.cs:

```
public interface ICommentDAL<T> where T : BaseEntity<int>, IBaseDAL<T, int>
{
    int Save(WebsiteContext ctx, NewCommentDTO nc, string who);
    ....
}
```

CommentDAL.cs:

```
public class CommentDAL<T>
    where T : BaseEntity<int>, IBaseDAL<T, int>, ICommentDAL<T>
{
    BaseDAL<T, int> baseDAL = new BaseDAL<T, int>();

    public int Save(WebsiteContext ctx, NewCommentDTO<T> nc, string who)
    {
        ORM.Content.PageComment pc = new PageComment()
        {
            Body = nc.Body,
            ...
        };
        baseDAL.Save(pc as T, who, ctx);
    }
}
```

ORM.Content.PageComment class must use as T

but, if i write "T.", coming BaseEntity fields..

in serviceLayer, i will call commentDAL.Save method:

_commentDAL.Save(...);

how can i pass values T class in commentDAL.Save()

Comment: so, you want ```T : BaseX<T, I> {..}``` or ```T : BaseY<T, I> {..}``` ?

Comment: The T in base x needs to be a Base Y

Comment: There's no "inheritance" of generic type constraints - you have to explicitly include any constraints required by your base types or interfaces.

Comment: Your error message tells you exactly what you're doing wrong...

Comment: when i call "IMyClass", i want to give a class (T) and a type (I) (guid or int etc..) and T type and I type injected to IBaseX..

Comment: C# doesn't not support independent multiple inheritance, If you need a type to inherit from 2 concrete classes then 1 of your concrete classes needs to derive from the other

Comment: Please edit your question with additional information instead of writing comments with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer below, but please note you should probably tell more about your intended type design. Because just making some generics work for the compiler will probably not result in the code that you actually want.

The following works:

```
public class BaseY<T>
{

}
public interface IBaseX<T, I>
       where T : BaseY<I>
{
}
public class BaseX<T, I> : IBaseX<T, I>
       where T : BaseY<I>
{
}

// it works but,

public interface IMyClass<T, I>
       where T : BaseY<I>, IBaseX<T, I>
{
}
public class MyClass<T, I>
       where T : BaseY<I>, IBaseX<T, I>, IMyClass<T, I>
{
}
```

Note, you can not constrain `T` to two classes, so you can't say `where T : BaseY<I>, BaseX<T, I>, IMyClass<T, I>`. Instead, in order for your construct to make any sense, `BaseX` and `BaseY` would need to be in an inheritance hierarchy and you can write the constraint for the more derived class.

---

Considering your updated structure, I think you should change as follows:

```
// from
public interface ICommentDAL<T> where T : BaseEntity<int>, IBaseDAL<T, int>
// to
public interface ICommentDAL<T> : IBaseDAL<T, int>
    where T : BaseEntity<int>
// or to
public interface ICommentDAL : IBaseDAL<PageComment, int>
```

Because this would actually create a DAL hierarchy with type constraints on the model instead of mixing in some DAL type constraints that are not valid for model classes.

The other definition needs similar changes:

```
// from
public class CommentDAL<T>
    where T : BaseEntity<int>, IBaseDAL<T, int>, ICommentDAL<T>
// to
public class CommentDAL<T> : BaseDAL<T, int>, ICommentDAL<T>
    where T : BaseEntity<int>
// or to
public class CommentDAL : BaseDAL<PageComment, int>, ICommentDAL
```

Since you explicitely work with `PageComment` inside `CommentDAL` anyway (`PageComment pc = new PageComment() ...`) I would opt for the design without any generic parameter on the `CommentDAL` level.

Comment: thanks a lot.. @grek40
[br]

[code]
public interface IMyClass<T, I>
       where T : BaseY<I>, IBaseX<T, I>[code]
[br]
but second not as you said..
[br]
i cant understand : "Instead, in order for your construct to make any sense, BaseX and BaseY would need to be in an inheritance hierarchy and you can write the constraint for the more derived class."

Comment: @MehmetGenç __if__ `BaseY<T>` is a `class` __and__ `T : BaseY<I>` __and__ `T : BaseX<T, I>` is required (`T` derives from both classes), __then__ `BaseX<T, I>` and `BaseY<I>` must be part of the same inheritance hierarchy and __because C# doesn't allow multi-inheritance__, this implies that `BaseY<I> : BaseX<T, I>` __or__ `BaseX<T, I> : BaseY<I>` must be true, so one of them would be the more derived class. (There can be intermediate classes in the hierarchy between those two, but one must be the ancestor of the other)

Comment: thank you for your help. Now no error but i cant access the PageComment by T. i think, i must create more ICommentDAL and CommentDAL classes each coming class.. Forexample; (CommentForPageCommentDAL, ICommentForPageCommentDAL), (CommentForNewsCommentDAL, ICommentForNewsCommentDAL)
<br><br>
as it will code repeats..

Comment: @MehmetGenç it all depends on where and how you try to do things with `T`. If you have a lot of similar stuff that's not the same, your idea of using generics is not bad, just make sure to keep the structure clean - which requires a decent understanding of the generic concept-

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IMyClass<T, I> 
    where T : IBaseX<T, I>
{ }
```

This will fail because according to `IBaseX<T, I>`, `T` is constrained to be of type `BaseY<I>`. However, the definition for `IMyClass<T, I>` does not have that constraint, so the restriction for `T` is not enforced.

Note that transitive constraints are not carried over, and you need to list them explicitly again:

```
public interface IMyClass<T, I>
    where T : BaseY<I>, IBaseX<T, I>
{ }
```

Similarly, you also need to specify a constraint for `T` for `MyClass<T, I>`. However, there the constraint would be on both `BaseX<T, I>` and `BaseY<I>` which are both classes, so this does not work since .NET does not support multiple inheritance. You could use the `IBaseX<T, I>` interface though:

```
public class MyClass<T, I>
    where T : BaseY<I>, IBaseX<T, I>, IMyClass<T, I>
{ }
```